# Whats wrong with my function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I don't know why this is not working. The function call at the bottom of 
 displayWorld();  if you commit that line out and then console.log in the console it works. But if I call the function in the code it breaks.

sorry here error

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null
>       at displayWorld (index.html:40)
>       at index.html:43

The HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Pacman Demo</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"></style>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js'></script> 
  <script type="text/javascript">

  var world = [
              [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],
              [2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,1,2],
              [2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2,1,2],
              [2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2],
              [2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2],
              [2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2],
              [2,1,1,1,1,1,2,1,1,2],
              [2,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2],
              [2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2],

            ];


            function displayWorld(){
                var output = '';

                for(var i=0; i<world.length; i++){
                    output += "\n<div class='row'>";
                    for(var j=0; j<world[i].length; j++){
                        if(world[i][j] == 2)
                            output += "\n\t<div class='brick'></div>";
                        else if(world[i][j] == 1)
                            output += "\n\t<div class='coin'></div>";
                        if(world[i][j] == 0)
                            output += "<\n\tdiv class='empty'></div>";
                    }
                    output += "\n</div>";
                }
                console.log(output);
                document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
            }

     displayWorld();      <----- this piece here
  </script>


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id='world'></div>


</body>
</html>
```

The CSS

```
/*CSS reset settings here*/
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: black ;
}
div.row div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.brick {
    background-color: blue;

}

div.coin{
    background: url(coin.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}

div.packman{
    background: url(mrpacman.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}

div.empty{


}
```

Comment: First of all, you have really wrong tags placed. For example `</style>` is placed but i dont see your style tag being opened anywhere.

Comment: What does "it breaks" mean? Do you get any errors in the console? (If you're getting an error on the line `document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;` then Gerardo's suggestion should fix that.)

Comment: Are you getting any error in console? If yes, share the error message.

Comment: ---> `"<\n\tdiv class='empty'></div>"`

Comment: ...and the `world` element doesn't exist yet when the function is invoked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think its because you are loading the js file before the div tag its created, put the script at the end of the body and that should fix it

Answer (score 1):

To fully understand why this happens you should understand how `HTML` + `CSS` + `JS` model works. I described the full page loading and execution logic as it might help you understand similar issues. If you're only interested in the current error, skip to point 3.

1. No `JavaScript` is executed before [`CSSOM`](https://www.w3.org/TR/cssom-1/) is built (to prevent [`FOUC`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_of_unstyled_content)).
2. CSSOM is built after `<head>` is read and parsed.
   This is why you need to place all your styleseets and `<style>` tags in `<head>`. If you place them in `<body>`, FOUC becomes possible on the contents preceeding the `<style>` in body, because it is first rendered without those rules.
3. `<script>` tags are read and executed in order of appearance as soon as they are met. The ones already loaded from `<head>` are executed before the `<body>` tag is added to `DOM`, in the order they were encountered. The `<script>` tags inside `<body>` are executed when they are met, as `DOM` is being built, ***but before the rest of the page (following content) has been added to `DOM`***.

This means your `<script>` tag is executed before `<div id="world"></div>` has been created in `DOM` and your script, trying to add content to it with this line...

```
document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
```

... results in an error, as `document.getElementById('world')` returns `null` at that point and `null` doesn't have an `innerHTML` property.

To fix it, you should place your script in `<body>`, after the `#world` div:

```css
*{
 margin: 0px;
 padding: 0px;
}

body{
    background-color: black ;
}
div.row div{
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    display: inline-block;
}

div.brick {
    background-color: blue;

}

div.coin{
    background: url(coin.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}

div.packman{
    background: url(mrpacman.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;

}

div.empty{

}
```

```html
<div id="world"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
  var world = [
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2],
    [2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2],

];

function displayWorld() {
    var output = '';

    for (var i = 0; i < world.length; i++) {
        output += "\n<div class='row'>";
        for (var j = 0; j < world[i].length; j++) {
            if (world[i][j] == 2)
                output += "\n\t<div class='brick'></div>";
            else if (world[i][j] == 1)
                output += "\n\t<div class='coin'></div>";
            if (world[i][j] == 0)
                output += "<\n\tdiv class='empty'></div>";
        }
        output += "\n</div>";
    }
    document.getElementById('world').innerHTML = output;
}

displayWorld();
  </script>
```

As an alternative, you could delay the execution of your script by wrapping it inside

```
window.onload = function() {
  // your script here...
}
```

This will delay the execution of your script until `load` event is fired for `window`, which happens as soon as `</html>` is encountered and `DOM` is complete.

**Note:** your script does not include any `jQuery` code and, since your example doesn't need it, I removed it.